# Postgres: how to join closest value from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, self-join

I have a the following table

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
    id SERIAL,
    other_id INTEGER NOT NULL, -- some ForeignKey
    date DATE NOT NULL
)
```

I want to join this table to itself by previous (closest) `date` item with the same `other_id`. Something like

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM temp AS t1
JOIN temp AS t2 ON (t2.other_id = t1.other_id AND t2.date < t1.date)
```

But `t2.date` must be closest to `t1.date` (not any lower date).

Is that possible at all?

Comment: in each new raw date will increase right? i meant date is not random right?

Comment: With " But `t2.date` must be closest to `t1.date` (not any lower date). " you mean the date which is closest to `t1.date` from `t2` but is also after `t1.date`, right?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP date is random, not strict increased

Comment: @J.Schneider t2.date is closest smaller than t1.date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like the following:

```
WITH temp_rn AS (
  SELECT id, other_id, date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY other_id 
                            ORDER BY date) AS rn
  FROM temp
)
SELECT t1.*
FROM temp_rn AS t1
LEFT JOIN temp_rn AS t2 ON t1.other_id = t2.other_id AND t1.rn = t2.rn + 1
```

The query uses `ROW_NUMBER` in order to detect the 'previous' row: it is the one having the previous row number within the same `other_id` slice.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are after, but something like this might do it:

```
select count(*)
from temp as t1
  join lateral (
      select t.other_id, max(t.date)
      from temp as t 
      where t.date < t1.date
        and t.other_id = t1.other_id
      group by t2.other_id
  ) as t2 on t2.other_id = t1.other_id;
```